# Bloquear letra ñ con JavaScript en un Regex

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente regex que me valida correctamente un correo electrónico con JavaScript, pero no me bloquea caracteres como ñ tildes y necesito que los usuarios no los ingresen.

Ya intenté modificando el regex pero no me funciona.

```js
email_regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Comment: Habiendo tantas regex que ya se encargan de validar emails y funcionan, ¿por qué reinventar la rueda? Ejemplos: [link 1](https://emailregex.com/), [link 2](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Además, a la hora de validar emails, tienes que tener en mente si lo que quieres es evitar equivocaciones involuntarias o que el usuario ingrese algo malicioso. Yo recomiendo una validación sencilla con JavaScript para evitar errores comunes, y pero luego la validación completa sucede en el backend.

Comment: Se que ya todo se ha inventado pero como ya tenia un regex diseñado solo nesecitaba saber donde añadir las ñ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estuve probando tu expresión regular, creo que con esta pequeña modificación que le hice:

```
email_regex = /^(([^Ññ<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^Ññ<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

si ves le puse las Ññ donde tú ignoras los caracteres extraños:

```
(([^Ññ<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^Ññ<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)
```

También puedes probar vía Online tu Expresión Regular [aquí](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Funciona muy bien y entendi el concepto ignore esa parte y acomodaba los valores en otro lado muchas gracias

Comment: @AlexMachado excelente me alegro que te funciono.